# Data structure / algorithm to find current position of an identifier in array following many insertions

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

#### Summary

I have a problem that seems as if it is likely to have many good known solutions with different performance characteristics. Assuming this is the case, a great answer could include code (or pseudo code), but ideally, it would reference the literature and give them name of this problem so I can explore the problem in greater detail and understand the space of solutions.

#### The problem

I have an initially empty array that can hold identifiers. Any identifiers in the array are unique (they're only ever in the array once).

```
var identifiers: [Identifier] = []
```

Over time a process will insert identifiers in to the array. It won't just append them to the end. They can be inserted **anywhere** in the array.

Identifiers will never be removed from the array – only inserted.

**Insertion needs to be quick**, so probably the structure won't literally be an array, but something supporting better than linear time insertion (such as a BTree).

After some identifiers have been added to `identifiers`, I want to be able to query the current position of any given identifier. So I need a function to look this up.

A *linear time* solution to this is simply to scan through `identifiers` from the start until an `identifier` is found, and the answer is the index that was reached.

```
func find(identifier: Identifier) -> Int? {
  for index in identifiers.indices {
    if identifiers[index] == identifier {
      return index
    }
  }

  return nil
}
```

But this linear scaling with the size of the array is problematic if the array is very large (perhaps 100s of millions of elements).

#### A hash map doesn't work

We can't put the positions of the identifiers in to a hash map. This doesn't work because identifier positions are not fixed after insertion in to the array. If other identifiers are inserted before them, they will drift to higher indexes.

However, a possible acceleration for the linear time algorithm would be to cache the **initial** insertions position of an identifier and begin a linear scan from there. Because identifiers are only inserted, it must be at that index, or an index after it (or not in `identifiers` at all). Once the identifier is found, the cache can be updated.

Another option could be to update the hash-map after any insertions to correct any positions. However this would slow down insert so that it is potentially a linear time operation (as previously mentioned, `identifiers` is probably not a literally array but some other structure allowing better than linear time insertion).

#### Summary

There's a linear time solution, and there's an optimisation using a hash map (at the cost of roughly doubling storage). Is there a much better solution for looking up the current index of an identifier, perhaps in log time?

Comment: You could keep the position up to date if you increase all positions higher than the one inserted position). This would make insert a bit more expensive (O(n)).

Comment: Thanks @MrSmith42 – I should note I want insertion to also be fast – I'm not actually going to use an array to store `identifiers`, I'll use something that has better than linear time insertion. I'll clarify that.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark It should be expected to be completely random – when an identifier is inserted the insertion index is a flat distribution of the array's current size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [order-statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) for this, based on a red-black tree or other self-balancing binary tree. Essentially, each node will have an extra integer field, storing the number of descendants it currently has. (Insertion and deletion operations, and their resultant rotations, will only result in updating `O(log n)` nodes so this can be done efficiently). To query the position of an identifier, you examine the descendant count of its left subtree and the descendant counts of the siblings of each of its right-side ancestors.

Note that while the classic use of an order-statistic tree is for a sorted list, nothing in the logic requires this; "node A is before node B" is all you need for insertion, tree rotations don't require re-evaluating the ordering, and having a pointer to the node (and having nodes store parent pointers) is all you need to query the index. All operations are in `O(log n)`.

Comment: What's the mechanism here to retrieve the position of the identifier, given the identifier? What property is the tree ordered by?

Comment: @גלעדברקן My understanding of the answer is elements in the tree are reference types and keep track of their parent nodes (in the tree). A hash map can be used to look up the tree element (from an identifier). From here, the position can be determined using the order data stored in the tree's nodes.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yep. The ordering is derived from insertions (i.e. "insert B before A", meaning that B<A and C<B for C the previous predecessor of A). Just as if insertions were to an array, with elements following the inserted element being shifted one position to the right.

Comment: @Sneftel FWIW and almost completely off topic, I'm fairly sure that the approach described for an "order-statistic tree" can be applied such that any monoid (to which the elements can be mapped), which might be used for a running `scan` operation, can be similarly maintained in `log(n)` time. This seems like it ought to be really useful in a bunch of applications – although I'm not sure what they are! :-) Examples might be running elements products, sums, max, min, etc.

Comment: @Benjohn yep, any associative operation will work. That’s the basis of a Fenwick tree.